# copy a sqlite file into the storePath : nothing in there (core data)

Tags: objective-c, core-data

i created a sqlite file with "Lita", i copied it (dragging it) into xcode in the "Other Sources" folder (and i checked the square to copy the file). I then tried to check wether the file is copied or not, but in this folder : there is nothing copied into Documents? :

```
my path : /Users/MyProfile/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.3/Applications/154BC5C5-FF55-48B5-A7A0-A80496212ACB/Documents
```

and my code that should copy it, or maybe there's something i misunderstood?

```
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator {

    if (persistentStoreCoordinator_ != nil) {
        return persistentStoreCoordinator_;
    }

    NSLog(@"my path : %@",self.applicationDocumentsDirectory);
    NSString *storePath = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"myCD.sqlite"];
    /*
     Set up the store.
     For the sake of illustration, provide a pre-populated default store.
     */
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    // If the expected store doesn't exist, copy the default store.
    if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:storePath]) {
        NSString *defaultStorePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myCD" ofType:@"sqlite"];
        if (defaultStorePath) {
            NSLog(@"in if defaultStorePath");
            [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultStorePath toPath:storePath error:NULL];
        }
    }
```

So the sqlite file should be copied into the iphone simulator/4.3/etc. but nothing is in there...

Thanks

Comment: The obvious next step is to pass a real NSError* to copyItemAtPath:toPath: instead of passing NULL, so you can see if that's where the problem is happening.

Comment: @rob mayoff : thanks, i've got no error, i think it's a problem when i create my db : do you know `Lita`? it's a very simple software to create sql files, http://www.dehats.com/drupal/?q=node/58 i installed it, i create a database, but if i put an extension like ".sqlite" to my file, i can't re-open it with Lita, the file looks like it is empty. And if i create the table and don't put any extension to the file (just a name), i can re-open the file in the software, but it won't be copied with filemanager and won't work because it's not a ".sqlite"... any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are properly copying the file.

However, if it is not a Core Data generated store file, Core Data cannot use it as a store.

Core Data is not a simple SQLite wrapper but instead using a SQLite store is but one of the Core Data store options. Core Data has to structure the store in a specific way and the Core Data sqlite schema is undocumented. You can't just drop any SQLite file in and use it as a Core Data store.

You will need to import the data into Core Data and have Core Data create the store and write data to it. Then you can include that file in the app bundle.

Comment: thanks TechZen, can you explain a little bit your last sentence? `import the data into Core Data` ? how to pre-populate a file, as they seem to ask in the comments of the appDelegate, if i cannot directly put my sqlite file when creating my project?

Comment: If you have an exiting SQL file, you would (1) create a utility project using the same data model and classes as your app. (2) Import the SQL using the C API and (3) populate the managed objects with the SQL derived data (4) save the managed object context. That will give you a persistent store file that you add to your app bundle.

Comment: thanks TechZen for your answer, i searched some tutorials to understand what you said, i found a good one : `www.raywenderlich.com/980/core-data-tutorial-how-to-preloadimport-existing-data` but i was still wondering, what is a utility project? 2.what C API are you talking about? the link above shows how to use python, do you any link that explains the C api? and, at the end you say i've got a persistent store, in the tutorial i read, it seems that we end up with a new filled "sqlite" file, what do you mean by a persistent store, is it a particular file? or is it located in the code?

Comment: (1) A utility project is any Xcode project not intended to create an app. In this case, it will run code to populate the persistent store. (2) The standard SQL C-API. It's SQLite3 on Mac IIRC. (3) The persistent store is the file in which the data is written to disk. It has its own name because their are several persistent formats and all are collective referred to as persistent stores. In this case, the file will be an `.sqlite` file but that won't always be true.