# Error while creating coredata file in unit test

Tags: ios, unit-testing, core-data

I have a coredata file in a static library and I'm creating unit tests for it. I get this error when i try to create the sqlite file in the following step during the unit test execution

```
_persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
    if (![_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType
                                                   configuration:nil
                                                             URL:storeURL
                                                         options:nil
                                                           error:&error])
    { [...] }
```

> Test Case '-[PersonTest testAddPerson]' started. 2012-10-12
>   07:19:23.989 otest[11852:7e03] Unresolved error Error
>   Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=512 "The operation couldn’t be
>   completed. (Cocoa error 512.)" UserInfo=0x216a320 {reason=Failed to
>   create file; code = 2}, {
>       reason = "Failed to create file; code = 2"; }

Answer (score 0):

Try giving the .sqlite file the exact same name as the project name.

Also

Make sure you copy the .sqlite file from your library and save it to the applications directory.

Comment: I have named the .sqlite file to be exact as the project name and even the .xcmodeldata file is the same. In my unit test target I've also included the .sqlite file.

Comment: @IphoneDeveloper check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7906330/copy-a-sqlite-file-into-the-storepath-nothing-in-there-core-data. Are you copying the file?